# how to launch multiple instances with different subnet ids using ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to use Ansible to create two instances, each instance must have different subnet `ids`. I'm using `exact_count` with tag Name to keep track of instances. The main issue is that I am not able to understand how to provide two different subnet `ids` in the same playbook.

Comment: Hi Nitesh, welcome to SO. Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, paying especial attention to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section. In order to be successful, we will need to know what you have already tried, and what errors or bad outcomes you are experiencing. Posting a representative sample of your playbook task can help -- not the whole thing, that's the "M" in "MCVE"

Comment: that might help you, just use the list of subnets id with loop. https://github.com/arbabnazar/ansible-aws-roles/blob/master/roles/ec2instance/tasks/main.yml#L37

Answer (score 1):

This task can be used in order to create the multiple ec2 instances with different subnets

```
 - name: 7. Create EC2 server
   ec2:
        image: "{{ image }}"
        wait: true
        instance_type: t2.micro
        group_id: "{{ security_group.group_id }}"
        vpc_subnet_id: "{{ item }}"
        key_name: "{{ key_name }}"  
        count: 1
        region: us-east-1
   with_items: 
        - "{{ subnet1.subnet.id }}"
        - "{{ subnet2.subnet.id }}"
   register: ec2
```